# capturing Command Line termination during installation

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script which automates the installation of ffmpeg on our servers. So far it works. On order to make the script more user-friendly, I would like to introduce something into the script which captures termination of the installation using Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z etc and gives an output like "Terminating at user request.." or something of that sort. Thing is, I don't know if it is possible to capture those characters by the script. I have searched and found about the Bash builtin trap command from [here](http://hacktux.com/bash/control/c) and would like to know if that is the right way to go.. If it is, just like control_c() is there and equivalent control_z()?

any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, using [`trap`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/trap/) is the way to go

```
control_c()
# run if user hits control-c
{
  echo -en "\n*** Ouch! Exiting ***\n"
  cleanup
  exit $?
}

# trap keyboard interrupt (control-c)
trap control_c SIGINT
```

and to trap the signal sent with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> key, you need to trap the [`SIGTSTP`](http://www.ucs.cam.ac.uk/docs/course-notes/unix-courses/Building/files/signals.pdf) signal:

```
control_z()
{
  echo -e "\n*** Suspending asked... Exiting! ***"
  cleanup
  exit $?
}

trap control_z SIGTSTP
```